# Unable to retrive data from webservice ionic1 framework

Tags: php, html, mysql, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to `ionic1 framework` and working on *`sidemenu ionic app`*. I want to get list of playlist from `Mysql Database`.
I have tried this in my **controller.js** :

```
.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
$http.get("#/php/list.php")
.success(function (response) {

    $scope.playlists = response.records;
    });

console.log($scope.playlists);

 })
```

**Php file code** :

```
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
$json[] =array('title'=>'Reggae','id'=>1);
$json[] =array('title'=>'test','id'=>2);
echo json_encode($json);
```

*It gives undefined*.
Please help me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works asynchron. That is why you add an anonymous function to retrieve the data.

The `console.log` is called right after the request but before the response is there. So `$scope.playlists` is empty.

You have to put the `console.log` inside the success callback to see the result.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer as i have put `console.log`  inside the success callback but no luck It gives undefined.

Comment: Did you test `console.log(response)`? Why is there a `#` in front of the url?

Comment: Yes i have tested  `console.log(response)` it gives code of index.html file. and if i removed # in front of URL its gives 404 error.

Comment: You should add the real URL for your PHP Script as parameter - btw what happens if you go within your browser to that script?

Comment: If i use URL like [http://example.com/webservices/list.php](http://example.com/webservices/list.php) it gives                  `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/webservices/list.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.1.101:8100' is therefore not allowed access.` And direct run url it gives json.

Comment: Add `OPTIONS` to `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`

Comment: I also tried                                                                `$http.get("php/list.php")
.then(function(response){
  alert(response.data);
   console.log(response);
   $scope.playlists = response;
});  `    but it getting back the entire PHP file, not processed by the server.

Comment: @NupurJain first put the url php/list.php(full url) in your browser and see if you get a proper json.